# VBA - another userfom open itself while I don't code this order

Tags: vba, excel, userform

First of all, I'm sorry for my english speaking.
I test a code in order to implement a list of item for a business. My userform is use to search an item regarding other item which is linked. The valid bouton is used to search that and write the links on other listbox. When I click on the valid bouton, another userform open it. I don't understand why. 
This is my code regarding this userform, can you explain me why vba do this ?

```
Private Sub valider_Click()
Dim i As Integer

subcat2.Enabled = True
cat2.Enabled = True
fami2.Enabled = True
depar2.Enabled = True

i = 1
While nom2 <> Feuil1.Cells(i, 1)
i = i + 1
Wend

subcat2 = Feuil1.Cells(i, 2)
cat2 = Feuil1.Cells(i, 3)
fami2 = Feuil1.Cells(i, 4)
depar2 = Feuil1.Cells(i, 5)

End Sub
```

Tkank you,

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a breakpoint in the valider_Click() method and running in debug mode and clicking the button.

If your program hits the breakpoint, then the button is wired to the event handler method correctly.

Otherwise, look at the button properties to see whether it's wired to the right event.  Maybe it's accidentally wired to something that opens the other form?